# Simple animated CSS 3 menu

Tags: html, css

I am a new HTML/CSS guy, and I want to learn HTML and CSS. Now I saw this wonderful [website](http://www.deltalaminates.in/); when you hover over the about us tab in the menu there is an animation on the submenu. That's the animation that I tried re-creating.

Here's what I have tried: [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/w05h2qec/).

Now, it all works fine, below is the CSS that actually does the trick:

```
.menu > li a:hover ~ .sub-menu{
    display: block;
    -webkit-animation-name: smallanim;
    -o-animation-name: smallanim;
    animation-name: smallanim;
    -webkit-animation-duration: .5s;
    -o-animation-duration: .5s;
    animation-duration: .5s;

}

@keyframes smallanim {
    0% {
        transform:translateY(20px);
    }
    100% {
        transform:translateY(0px);  
    }
}
```

It's `.menu > li a:hover ~ .sub-menu` this selection that basically does the trick. But is this the right way to do it? If you hover on the main menu the submenu appears, but then when you try hovering on the sub-menu, the menu disappears. Do I need to use jQuery?

Comment: You need `.menu > li:hover a ~ .sub-menu` instead of `.menu > li a:hover ~ .sub-menu`

Comment: @BatuZet post tat as an answer and take away 25 browny points !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do

`.menu > li:hover a ~ .sub-menu`

instead of

`.menu > li a:hover ~ .sub-menu`